# SonarQube LDAP: Search for Account in Sonarqube "Administration -> Secruity -> User ->Search"

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

SonarQube LDAP
I want to Search for a Account in **SonarQube**

> Administration -> Security -> User ->Search

The premise is that this account has not been logged in SonarQube. But the account exists in LDAP.
But if the account has been logged in **SonarQube**,it can be searched.

My goal is to group and authorize the known LDAP accounts in advance. 
thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever since SONAR-8715 was implemented in 6.3, it has been possible to provision non-local users. Your use-case is pretty well described in that ticket, and you can make use of the POST api/users/create Web API. This is only possible through the Web API, not the UI.

Once your users are created, they can be assigned permissions that persist when a user logs in for the first time.

Check out your own instance’s Web API documentation for the most relevant information for your version of SonarQube.